# Expectation and variance of the maximum likelihood estimator

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, statistical-inference

Suppose we have some data $\{data\}$ arising from one distribution described by an unknown set of parameters $X_0$ that we want to estimate.
The maximum likelihood procedure (under a uniform prior) provides us with the following estimator:

$\hat{MLE} = argmax_Y \ \  L(\{data\}| Y)$

which we can regard as a random variable, given that the data are random. I try to indicate random variables with an hat. Also the likelihood itself can be regarded as a random variable (parametrically dependent on Y, if we want: a random density), $\hat{L}(\{data\}|Y)$ and it seems possible to define as well:

$\hat{\mu}=\int  \ Y \hat{L}(\{data\}|Y)  \ dY$

and

$\hat{\sigma^2}=\int \ (Y -\hat{\mu})^2 \  \hat{L}(\{data\}|Y) \  dY$

How are these random variables related? Do we have to expect that generally (maybe not always...):

1. $E[\hat{MLE}] = X_0$ ?
2. $E[\hat{\sigma^2}] = \sigma^2[\hat{MLE}]$ ?
3. $E[\hat{\mu}] = X_0$ ?

I know that point (1) is not always true (as the mle estimator for the variance has a factor of 1/N instead of 1/(N-1) ), but the others? And "how much" point (1) is false? I guess something similar must be true...

Comment: The answer is distribution dependent. You can see that $\hat{MLE}$ is the mode of $Y$, and $\hat\mu$ is the mean of $Y$. So, basically, the difference between them is the general difference between mode and mean.

Comment: Thanks a lot for noticing. I understand that $\hat{MLE}$ and $\hat{\mu}$ are exactly those random variables and therefore are different. It remains true that the can have the same expectation value? Any comment about point (1) by itself or point (2) ?